# Efficient way to query in SQL a table with relationships within that table who are also not in another table

Tags: sql

A related example:

```
table activity
activity id | title
1             a
2             a2
3             b
4             b2

table people
id | parent id | activity id | active
```

Grab all the people who:

- is in a specific activity without a parent
- is in a specific activity who's parent is not in the same activity + not in the same related activity (ie: a, a2)

So far I have something less than ideal:

```
SELECT p.pid FROM people p
left join activity a
on p.activityid = a.activityid
where p.active = 1
and a.title = 'a'
and EXISTS (
    SELECT p1.pid from people p1
    left join activity a1
    on p1.activityid = a1.activityid
    where p.parentid = p1.id
    and a1.activityid != p.activityid
    or p.parentid = 0
)
```

This doesn't account for parentids not 'a2' or 'b2' etc..
The thing is I have the target activity id I want, but not the related activity, so I figured I'd somehow use the title instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a outer join. The `not exixts` clause will filer out someone without parents.

```
SELECT p.pid 
FROM people p,  activity a 
WHERE p.activityid = a.activityid 
AND p.active = 1 AND a.title = 'a' 
AND NOT EXISTS
( SELECT 1 FROM people pp, activity pa
  WHERE p.parentid = pp.id AND pp.activityid = pa.activityid
  AND pa.title NOT LIKE a.title||'%'
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get this to work with what I had to do. Ended up adding an IN clause to the inner select. BTW, SQL didn't like the || '%'.

Much faster than my previous attempt :)

Comment: If you are on SQL Server use `+` for string concatation instead of `||`. The Later is for Oracle.